# How do you delete a non-numeric column from an input dataset?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

For example, if I want to consider a flower species, number of petals, germination time and user `ID`, the user `ID` is going to have a hyphen in there. So in my data analysis, I don't want to use it. I'm aware that I can hard code it in, but I want to make it so when I input any dataset, it will automatically remove columns with `non-numeric` inputs.

Edit: Unclear question. I'm reading in data from a csv file using pandas.

Example:

```
        Species    NPetals    GermTime    UserID
    1    R. G        5          4           65-78

    2    R. F        5          3           65-81
```

I want to remove the `UserID` and `Species` columns from the `dataset`.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. To start with, what format is your data in? SQL database? CSV? Excel? Pandas dataframe? Please see the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've clarified some points.

Comment: So what's wrong with `del df['Species']` and `del df['UserID']`?

Comment: That's fine for this particular dataset, but I do want to make it more intelligent. If I use another dataset, it should automatically remove the non-numeric columns. I don't want to change the code every time I change the dataset.

Comment: So set up a little `if` loop testing the `dtype` of each column...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs you can just select the numeric data by filtering using [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html?highlight=dtypes#pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes):

```
In [5]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(6).astype('f4'),'b': [True, False] * 3,'c': [1.0, 2.0] * 3})
df

Out[5]:
          a      b  c
0  0.338710   True  1
1  1.530095  False  2
2 -0.048261   True  1
3 -0.505742  False  2
4  0.729667   True  1
5 -0.634482  False  2

In [15]:    
df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])

Out[15]:
          a  c
0  0.338710  1
1  1.530095  2
2 -0.048261  1
3 -0.505742  2
4  0.729667  1
5 -0.634482  2
```

You can pass any valid [np dtype hierarchy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html)