# Find and delete non numeric columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with 250+ columns. The majority of the columns contain floats but there are some columns that are strings. How do I search for columns that contain non-floats and delete them?

Comment: It's similar but I need it on columns rather than rows.

Comment: is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376937/how-do-you-delete-a-non-numeric-column-from-an-input-dataset/33378662#33378662) what you're after